Creating PrestaShop order programmatically via API call
I am creating a PrestaShop >8 module which will be handling connections with a marketplace.
The marketplace has two options for delivery / courier choice for end-users - it can be either courier (delivery to door) or locker pick-up; users will not be choosing any specific couriers.
Retailer defines their own delivery fee and free delivery threshold (one amount, same for both types of delivery).
We'll skip the products synchronisation process here as this works with no problems at all.
I have some problems with order create though. The module exposes an endpoint which handles and creates the order based on the request. Main problem is with choosing a carrier and delivery fees to have correct amounts. The delivery fee is calculated based on the delivery_fee and total amount vs threshold (simply - if the total amount is lower than the free delivery threshold then it's delivery_fee; otherwise it's 0). I am not able to set a delivery fee manually while creating order or can't find a way to do it.
With a simple case it worked well; problem is when the carrier delivery fee is somehow calculated differently in presta than it is in marketplace. I want the marketplace total and delivery fees to be final price(s).
Is there any way to create a PrestaShop order with a "generic" (non-visible) carrier with fee equal to 0 and add a "delivery" OrderItem to the Order while creating so that all amounts are correct?
I tried to:

Create a carrier with specific threshold and assigning the carrier to order. It goes correctly to the $cart->carrier_id but after order is created the carrier_id is different in Order (even though the id was correct)

Create order with any carrier and then updateOrderDeliveryFee but ... it doesn't work as the order validation fails

Find any specific methods to update delivery fee for cart / carrier; update order shipping price manually one-time only. No success till now. Seem that prestashop is quite messed up


